# what encoding stackoverflow used in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I can not save the character  𝑴  in my mysql which encoding is utf8, but i found stackoverflow can save it and display it.

I made a mistake. stackoverflow also can not save 𝑴 .

Comment: stackoverflow uses sql server, not mysql.  What made you think otherwise?

Comment: i thought stackoverflow uses php & mysql, because it is so fast.
Now i know i made a mistake. thanks for your explanation.

Comment: You might enjoy listening to the StackOverflow podcast.  Joel and Jeff talk fairly regularly about implementation of StackOverflow.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't store the character, you are encoding or decoding it incorrectly, or converting it to a character set that doesn't support the character.

The UTF-8 encoding can handle almost any character that exists in any language, so it's quite unlikely that it's a limitation of that encoding.

You have to use the Unicode character set or some Unicode encoding (UTF-7, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32) for all steps of the process. If you convert the text to some other character set and then back, you can only support the characters of that specific character set.

Comment: i found they are Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols(http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/pfpopup.php?page=1D&subpage=4), how to treat them correctly in DB?

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is trying to display the character as `&#119924`. So maybe that character value is being saved in the database (certainly *some* character value is being saved in the database), but the reason why we can't see that character is because of the font which is being used to display the HTML: perhaps it's the font being used, not the database, that doesn't support that character value.

Comment: I changed the character to &#119924 so you can see it in firefox but not IE, And stackoverflow can not save it in to DB.